# Python ssh read image

Tags: python, opencv, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I am using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4. I want to read and show the image from the remote machine. Then, I try to use the library **`paramiko`**. However, I cannot read the file.

Here is my code. First, I import all libraries and setup connection:

```
import paramiko
import cv2
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
s.connect("XXX.XXX.XXX",22,username="NAME",password='PW',timeout=4)
```

Second, I open an SFTP session and open the target image:

```
sftp = s.open_sftp()
remote_file = sftp.open('/home/frame/image.jpg')
```

I try to print the `remote_file` : `print remote_file`

It returns `**paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile object at 0x000000000572AC50**`

Finally, I try to read and show the image:

```
img = cv2.imread(remote_file)
cv2.imshow("image", img)
```

However, error comes out:

> ```
>   File "ssh.py", line 25, in <module>
>     img = cv2.imread(remote_file)
> TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, SFTPFile found
> ```

_________________________________________________________________________-

I am asking for help how can I read the image from another remote machine. Is my way to do is correct? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you expect that `imread` (which accepts a path to a file) will work with an object of type `SFTPFile`? You best chance is to get the binary file out of the `SFTPFile`, and then use `imdecode`

Comment: @Miki Thanks for your reply. How can I get the binary file (or string) out from the `SFTPFile` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a solution:

```
import numpy as np

...

sftp = s.open_sftp()
with sftp.open('/home/frame/image.jpg') as f:
  img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(f.read(), np.uint8), 1)

cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```